# C++ input/output error

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct arr{
    int n[100];
    int array[99];
};


int main(){
    int t,i=0,temp1[10],temp2[10],c1=0,c2=0;
    arr A[100];
    cin>>t;
    cout<<endl;
    if(t>=1 && t<=100)
    {
        while(i<t)
        {
            cin>>A[i].n;
            if(A[i].n%2==0)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<A[i].n;j++)
                {
                    cin>>A[i].array[j];
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                cout<<"\n Program Terminated";
                break;
            }
            cout<<endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
       cout<<"Program terminated";
    return 0; 
}
```

> Blockquote

This is the code that i wrote but am getting error - [Error] no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}' and 'int [100]')
This is the first time i have encountered such error

Comment: Try to format the question carefully please.

Comment: There isn't any operator defined to input an array of int directly. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I can't think of how that error message could be any clearer: there is no operator >> for pulling data off an input stream into (as in fill) an `int[100]` array. You have to do it (usually some sort of iteration). And Fyi, there is no modulus operator taking the left-side of an array either, which is the next line in your program, and likely also complaining. And, of course, there is no `operator <` taking a native array as an operand either. Thsi code looks like `n` shouldn't even be an array. So why is it?

Answer (score 0):

A guess but I think correct. The error is here

```
struct arr
{
    int n[100];
    int array[99];
};
```

What you really meant to say is

```
struct arr
{
    int n;
    int array[99];
};
```

I.e. in your code `n` is the number of elements in the array. So `n` should not be an array, it should be an integer.

Choosing better names that `n` is also a good idea of course. If you'd named it `size` instead then things would have been clearer, maybe even to yourself.